# textcomp's \textmusicalnote doesn't work: "cannot open encoding file for reading"

Tags: errors, music, textcomp

I'd like to put a music note as an icon next to notes in my document. I discovered the `\textmusicalnote` symbol in the `textcomp` package, but it doesn't seem to render.

I suspect I'm doing something obviously wrong, but I can't see what right now.

I'm using the `memoir` class, but in an effort to create a minimal document I've tried using the standard `article` class. Here's my document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}

Here is a note:

\textmusicalnote

or not, as the case may be.

\end{document}
```

Nothing appears at all where I'm expecting to see the quaver.

Is there a better way to do this?

---

Edit:
The end of my log file shows:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file cm-super-ts1.enc): cannot open encoding file for reading ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: I obtain the quaver when I process your code. What LaTeX system are you using?

Comment: The same with me (quite recent texlive).  Are there any errors/warnings in the log file?

Comment: The end of my log file shows:!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file cm-super-ts1.enc): cannot open encoding file for 
reading
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Comment: I tried to match the title of your question to what's being discussed here. Although a general question about inserting musical notes would certainly be interesting, this seems to be more about solving the problem with `\textmusicalnote`. I also included the information from your comment in the question; it's usually preferable to have such important information right with the question. Editing the question is a legitimate way of answering a comment (you could add a note `@userXYZ: See my edit` if you like).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like I didn't have enough fonts installed. I ran this command as root

```
yum install 'texlive-cm-super*'
```

to install the complete cm-super font details.

Now I can see music! :-)

Comment: in my case, it was tex-cm-super, instead of texlive-cm-super

Answer (score 3):

For FreeBSD 10.0, the package "tex-dvipsk" contains the respective file.

```
pkg install tex-dvipsk
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error on Ubuntu.

Running `sudo apt-cache search tex | grep super` lead me to the package `cm-super`.

Simply running `sudo apt install cm-super` allowed me to create the PDF as expected.

I believe this error came after an auto-update of all my machine's packages, so that package must have slipped through the net.